# How to make an html change the value of a variable in java?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I used this format despite warnings:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        //code
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
```

How do I change the value of a variable when a button is pressed?

EX:

`out.println("<button><a href = 'home' action = "isLoggedIn = false">Logout</a></a>");`

This would be run from the homepage and basically refresh the page except the user would be logged out. What is the proper way of doing so?

Comment: Are you trying to have a variable value changed in java when a button is pressed using html? Maybe I don't understand enough of the question but I don't quit understand it.

Comment: use `jquery` `$("#buttonid").click(function(){});`

Comment: @Ducksause88 yes exactly

Comment: @Immer Allein I am building this in eclipse so how would I go about using JQuery and also I haven't heard many swell reviews about it.

Comment: Use jsp and ajax to do this.Writing html code in servlet will be painful.

Comment: I'm not bothered by it, `I used this format despite warnings`

Comment: Just write servlet to invalidate the session and redirect to the Home page on Clicking the logout button

Comment: `... also I haven't heard many swell reviews about it` - I guess you don't listen to the right people then

Comment: not reviews just comments on others questions saying don't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After user login,you need to create session and Once the user click the Logout Button,you need to invalidate by using `session.invalidate()` and then redirect to home page without any session.

Follow the below for reference

[Servlet Login and Logout](http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example)

This one use only servlets.I think this will help you :)

Comment: well how do you apply this to the button being pressed?

Comment: well I don't know that this shall be a permanent solution but I can work with it.